# Database transfer between servers

Tags: mysql, database, web-services, webserver, phpfox

How can I transfer my data from one database(000webhosting.com) to another(shatellhost.com)?
note: I use 000webhosting.com free hosting service and I cant create full backup. my data is phpfox social networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

000webhosting offers you a tool called phpmyadmin - here you can export your entire database and then you can import the exported file on your new hosting - you should have some information about connecting to database via phpmyadmin in hosting administration :)

Answer (score 1):

I have answered another question of yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295154/changing-mysql-database-address/). You can check the PHPFox documentation to find out how to config the database connection in your code, this is usually the same as when your first install the PHPFox.