# changing mysql database address

Tags: mysql

I asked this question 1 hour ago:

How can I transfer my data from one database(000webhosting.com) to another(shatellhost.com)? note: I use 000webhosting.com free hosting service and I can't create full backup. my data is phpfox social networking.

No one answered so I did this:

I transfered (download) whole data in public-html in 000webhosting.com to my computer and then uploded whole that to public-html of my new host in shotellhost.com, then when i try to open my site: www.ibiology.ir this appears:

```
Cannot connect to the database:
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql5.000webhost.com' (4)
```

How can i change MySQL address to new MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) and then import the SQL into your new database.

**backup**: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

**restore**:# mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql

Answer (score 1):

This error appears to be due to the configuration file of your PHP code, the connection information did not changed properly when you change the host.

First thing to do is make sure that you have change your database. Because of the security reason, most hosting service does not allow connecting to there mysql server from another location. There for, you connect to the `mysql5.000webhost.com` from another server.

Second, review the code to find out which file containing the database connection information, which usually includes: `database hostname`, `database username`, `database password`, `database name`. If you use an PHP framework, check the documentation.

In general, this is what I usually do when moving a site to another host:

- Open the PHPMyAdmin in my old host control panel
- Export the full data of the current database. I usually check `DROP TABLE/DROP VIEW` option.
- Save the exported sql file to my local drive
- Open the control panel of my new host
- Finding the MySQL configuration option. You may find the MySQL host name here, usualy is `localhost` (yes, 000webhost is a special case when not use this default host name).
- Create the database and the user if necessary.
- Write the `database hostname`, `database username`, `database password`, `database name` information properly into your php configuration file of your source code.
- Open the PHPMyAdmin in the control panel of the new host, go to my database (just created) and import the previous sql file.

If everything works well, your code may work.

Comment: Thank you. I did before. but it is not working properly. when I checked console log I see Core and environment errors.

Comment: So what is the error? Can you post them there. The "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql5.000webhost.com' (4)" error appears when you still use the old configuration in the PHP code. Maybe a review can help.